# Why does laravel parses my JS, CSS files and puts its content into HTML?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/main.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Its in my view, and the HTML output is:

`<style>.container{margin-top:55px}</style>` main.css 's content

`<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function(){console.log('loaded');})
//]]></script>`  main.js content

And the external CSS or JS file stays as a link, that works properly.

I really hate it, what is the proper way of linking files WITHOUT getting parsed into the HTML output?

Answer (score 1):

Use asset() [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers) function in your view file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

The files should be in `public/` directory.

You culd also try [elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir) which provides many features like *working with sass/less, sourcemaps, minification, versioning/cache busting*, etc.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, the linking is OK, but it puts the file's content into the HTML file. For example it replaces CSS `<link>`s with `<style>...</style>`

Comment: It does work as expected for me. There must be something which is affecting in your case. Tried removing **URL::** before the helper call and the slash **/** before css? If yes, check your version and open an issue I suggest.